# CASE statement issue

Tags: sql-server, case

Can anyone help with this error?

SQL:

```
SELECT 
    InvoiceDate, 
    BillingAddress, 
    BillingCity, 
    Total,

    CASE
      WHEN Total < 2.00 THEN 'Baseline Purchase'
      WHEN Total BETWEEN 2.00 AND 6.99 THEN 'Low Purchase'
      WHEN Total BETWEEN 7.00 AND 15.00 THEN 'Target Purchase'
      ELSE 'Top Performer'
    END AS PurchaseType

FROM 
    invoices
WHERE
  PurchaseType = 'Top Performer'
ORDER BY 
  BillingCity
```

Error:
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Invalid column name 'PurchaseType'.

Comment: Side note: `CASE` **expression**, not statement. SQL knows no flow control statements at all.

Answer (score 11):

This error is coming from your `WHERE` clause, not your `CASE` expression.

You say `WHERE  PurchaseType = 'Top Performer'`, however, `PurchaseType` is not a column in your table, so the query optimizer doesn't know what to do with it in as a search predicate.

There are a few ways to resolve this. One option is to copy/paste your `CASE` expression twice to appear in both the `WHERE` and `SELECT` clauses:

```
SELECT 
    InvoiceDate, 
    BillingAddress, 
    BillingCity, 
    Total,

    CASE
      WHEN Total < 2.00 THEN 'Baseline Purchase'
      WHEN Total BETWEEN 2.00 AND 6.99 THEN 'Low Purchase'
      WHEN Total BETWEEN 7.00 AND 15.00 THEN 'Target Purchase'
      ELSE 'Top Performer'
    END AS PurchaseType

FROM 
    invoices
WHERE
  CASE
      WHEN Total < 2.00 THEN 'Baseline Purchase'
      WHEN Total BETWEEN 2.00 AND 6.99 THEN 'Low Purchase'
      WHEN Total BETWEEN 7.00 AND 15.00 THEN 'Target Purchase'
      ELSE 'Top Performer'
    END = 'Top Performer'
ORDER BY 
  BillingCity
```

This is kind of "icky" because you're repeating yourself, and if you change that `CASE` expression, you'll need to change it in two places.

You could simplify the logic in the `WHERE` clause to not even need to use `CASE`, since you're filtering out anything but the "Top Performers" :

```
SELECT 
    InvoiceDate, 
    BillingAddress, 
    BillingCity, 
    Total,

    CASE
      WHEN Total < 2.00 THEN 'Baseline Purchase'
      WHEN Total BETWEEN 2.00 AND 6.99 THEN 'Low Purchase'
      WHEN Total BETWEEN 7.00 AND 15.00 THEN 'Target Purchase'
      ELSE 'Top Performer'
    END AS PurchaseType

FROM 
    invoices
WHERE Total > 15.00
ORDER BY 
  BillingCity
```

Or you could pop your query into a CTE, and then reference the CTE to perform your filtering. This will allow the optimizer to figure out that you want to do the computation of the `CASE` expression, then filter on the output of that:

```
WITH InvoiceData AS (
    SELECT 
        InvoiceDate, 
        BillingAddress, 
        BillingCity, 
        Total,

        CASE
          WHEN Total < 2.00 THEN 'Baseline Purchase'
          WHEN Total BETWEEN 2.00 AND 6.99 THEN 'Low Purchase'
          WHEN Total BETWEEN 7.00 AND 15.00 THEN 'Target Purchase'
          ELSE 'Top Performer'
        END AS PurchaseType

    FROM 
        invoices
)
SELECT *
FROM InvoiceData
WHERE
  PurchaseType = 'Top Performer'
ORDER BY 
  BillingCity
```

*edit*:
Since we don't have the table schema, the above queries all assuming the `Total` column is defined as something like `DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL`. If the column allows `NULL` values, or values more precise than 2 digits, then the `CASE` statement itself would need additional changes. Thanks to [ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993) for pointing out that I hadn't mentioned these additional potential pitfalls initially.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have the actual schema definition for the table. I decided to simply assume that OP's logic was correct, and therefore the invoice total is something like `DECIMAL (10,2) NOT NULL`. Made my answer cleaner. 

Answer (score 3):

Because of SQL's logical order of operations (`WHERE` is evaluated before `SELECT`), you **cannot** refer to a calculated value in the `SELECT` from the `WHERE` clause.

[@AMtwo](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/306070/220697) has provided some options. A cleaner solution in my opinion, is to place it into a `CROSS APPLY (VALUES`. Once you do that, you can refer to it in any later clauses.

```sql
SELECT 
    i.InvoiceDate, 
    i.BillingAddress, 
    i.BillingCity, 
    i.Total,
    v.PurchaseType

FROM 
    invoices i
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
    CASE
      WHEN i.Total < 2.00 THEN 'Baseline Purchase'
      WHEN i.Total >= 2.00 AND i.Total < 7.00 THEN 'Low Purchase'
      WHEN i.Total >= 7.00 AND i.Total < 15.00 THEN 'Target Purchase'
      ELSE 'Top Performer'
    END
) ) v(PurchaseType)
WHERE
  v.PurchaseType = 'Top Performer'
ORDER BY 
  BillingCity;
```

Obviously you can simplify this particular query, by removing the cases which do not match the correct `Total` anyway, but this demonstrates the principle behind this technique.

> Note also that `BETWEEN` can cause certain values to fall through the cracks. It is normally better to use a half-open interval `>= AND <`.

Comment: +1 for "WHERE before SELECT" - it's a fundamental "about face" in thinking about how things are done that most people new to relational databases miss.

Comment: Indeed, I normally start writing my queries `SELECT 1` just to keep the stupid Intellisense happy, then add the columns after. `BETWEEN` is another common mistake

Answer (score 1):

wrap your query and access from "outside" or in other words, query your query so you can use your composed fields as condition and grouping

This is alternative to `CROSS APPLY (VALUES` mentioned by [@Charlieface](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/220697/charlieface) that I use and I thinks it is clearest

```sql
SELECT * FROM (

    SELECT 
        InvoiceDate, 
        BillingAddress, 
        BillingCity, 
        Total,

        CASE
          WHEN Total < 2.00 THEN 'Baseline Purchase'
          WHEN Total BETWEEN 2.00 AND 6.99 THEN 'Low Purchase'
          WHEN Total BETWEEN 7.00 AND 15.00 THEN 'Target Purchase'
          ELSE 'Top Performer'
        END AS PurchaseType

    FROM 
        invoices

) AS sq

WHERE
  PurchaseType = 'Top Performer'
ORDER BY 
  BillingCity
```

Comment: Hi, please add some text to your answer, to explain what you did & why. Answers that are just an alternative query, without any explanation or context are much less helpful to the future folks who might find this and are experiencing the same problem

Comment: ok, thanks for tip